# GUI Connection to server problems

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jtable

Here is the GUI I have made......... When connecting to the server it is not stable however when it does connect it does not read the information from the database and display on the JTable inside the GUI. Underneath the first block of code is my server i made and the first block of code is GUI code. Can you kindly point out where I am going wrong as I can not figure it out......

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Component.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.SequentialGroup;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;

import Client_and_Server_Package.*;

public class Staff_GUI extends JFrame {
    Container con;

    JLabel lblWelcome = new JLabel("Welcome Staff");

    JButton btnView = new JButton("View");
    JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
    JButton btnLogout = new JButton("Logout");

    JTextField txtfilter = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField txtstatus = new JTextField(30);

    JTable table;

    Object[] possibilities = {"None", "Student Grades", "Students on the course", "Students on the Unit"};
    /*
    String[] columnName = {};


    private Connection conn;
    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet rs;*/
    Object[] [] data= {{}};
    protected ObjectOutputStream output; 
    protected ObjectInputStream input; 

    protected JTable message; 
    protected String chatServer; 
    protected Socket client;

    private RowFilter rf;
    private TableRowSorter sorter;

    TableModel model;

    public Staff_GUI(){
        super ("Staff");

        lblWelcome.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,24));

        con = getContentPane();
        con.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        /*
        class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {

            public int getColumnCount() {
                return columnName.length;
            }

            public int getRowCount() {
                return 10;
            }

            public String getColumnName(int col) {
                return columnName[col];
            }

            public Object getValueAt1(int row, int col) {
                return data[row][col];
            }

            public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
                return getValueAt1(0, c).getClass();
            }

             public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                if (col == 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

                        try {

                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            try {
                                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8",
                                        "Admin", "Cs170593cS");
                                stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from Student");

                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                String msg = "MyModel(): Error Connecting to Database:\n"
                                        + e.getMessage();
                                System.out.println(msg);
                            }
                        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            String msg = "The com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is missing\n"
                                    + "install and rerun the application";
                            System.out.println(msg);
                            System.exit(1);
                        } finally {
                            //fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
        }*/

        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.add(lblWelcome); top.add(new JLabel("                                                                                                                                                                                                        ")); top.add(btnView); top.add(btnUpdate); top.add(btnLogout);
        //top.resize(getPreferredSize());
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.ipady = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        con.add(top, c);

        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        //JPanel text = new JPanel();
        //text.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Disploay Area"));
        //MyModel model = new MyModel();
        //sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyModel>(model);
        //ListModel model = ListModel.createModelFromResultSet( rs );
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        //table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
                new ListSelectionListener() {
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                        int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                        if (viewRow < 0) {
                            //Selection got filtered away.
                            txtstatus.setText("");
                        } else {
                            int modelRow = 
                                table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow);
                            txtstatus.setText(
                                String.format("Selected Row in view: %d. " +
                                    "Selected Row in model: %d.", 
                                    viewRow, modelRow));
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textPanel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.ipadx = 800;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.ipady = 460;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        con.add(textPanel, c);

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.add(new JLabel("Filter"), BorderLayout.WEST); bottom.add(txtfilter);
        bottom.add(new JLabel("Status"), BorderLayout.WEST); bottom.add(txtstatus);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.ipadx = 5;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.ipady = 5;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        con.add(bottom, c);

        btnView.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                String options = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        con,
                        "What you want to View?",
                        "View",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        possibilities,
                        "None");
                if(options == possibilities[0]){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(con,
                            "You selected " + possibilities[0]
                            + "\nNo actions will be taken",
                            "Message",
                            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }


            }
        });


        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

            }
        });

        btnLogout.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                setVisible(false);
                Login_GUI log=new Login_GUI(); 
                log.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        pack();
        setSize(1025,600);
        setLocation(125,150);
        setVisible(true);
        //setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    private <MyModel> void newFilter() {
        RowFilter<MyModel, Object> rf = null;
        //If current expression doesn't parse, don't update.
        try {
            rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(txtfilter.getText(), 0);
        } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
            return;
        }
        TableRowSorter<MyModel> sorter;
        sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
    }

    public void runClient() //it execute while running client test-need to have in constructor
       {
          try 
          {
             connectToServer(); 
             getStreams(); 
             processConnection();
          } 
          catch ( EOFException eofException ) 
          {
             System.out.println( "\nClient terminated connection" );
          } 
          catch ( IOException ioException ) 
          {
             ioException.printStackTrace();
          } 
          finally 
          {
             closeConnection(); 
          } 
       } 


       public void connectToServer() throws IOException
       {      
          System.out.println( "Attempting connection\n" );


          client = new Socket( InetAddress.getByName( chatServer ), 12346 );


          System.out.println( "Connected to: " + 
             client.getInetAddress().getHostName() );
       } 


       public void getStreams() throws IOException
       {

          output = new ObjectOutputStream( client.getOutputStream() );      
          output.flush(); 


          input = new ObjectInputStream( client.getInputStream() );

          System.out.println( "\nGot I/O streams\n" );
       } 


       public void processConnection() throws IOException
       {


          do 
          { 

             try 
             {
                message = ( JTable ) input.readObject();
                message = (JTable) model;

             }catch ( ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException ){
                System.out.println( "\nUnknown object type received" );
             } 

          } while ( !message.equals( "SERVER>>> TERMINATE" ) );
       } 

       public void resiveData(Object model) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
          model = input.readObject();
       }

       public void closeConnection() 
       {
          System.out.println( "\nClosing connection" );


          try 
          {
             // close streams first, then socket
             output.close(); 
             input.close(); 
             client.close(); 
          } 
          catch ( IOException ioException ) 
          {
             ioException.printStackTrace();
          } 
       } 


       public void sendData( String message )
       {
          try 
          {
             output.writeObject( message );
             output.flush(); 

          } 
          catch ( IOException ioException )
          {
     //need to do smth!
          } 
       } 

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Staff_GUI staff_gui = new Staff_GUI();
        staff_gui.runClient();
    }

}
```

Comment: How can i post the server code as its too long???

Comment: Try to reduce it to a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Your database code and your GUI code should be in completely separate classes, only communicating through the application data model and the GUI data model.

Comment: I have minimal or below minimal knowledge of Client and Server and Database related things :(. 

My main task is to get information or data from the Database and then display it in the JTable, which is hosted inside of the GUI by using a Client and Server classes.

Comment: Is it possible to display or get any information or data from the Database and display it in JTable without using a AbstractTableModel class??

Comment: *"display it in JTable without using a AbstractTableModel class?"*  Certainly.  Use a `DefaultTableModel`.  Actually that just implements `AbstractTableModel` correctly, so you might want to explain why you think you need to avoid `AbstractTableModel`.